# rails - if condition on view - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class called @Subdomain:

Here is my controller:

```html
class SubdomainsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :set_subdomain, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :redirect_to_subdomain, only: :show
  before_action :redirect_to_subdomain_show, only: :root, unless: '@subdomain.nil?'

  def root
    render nothing: true
  end

  def index
    @subdomains = Subdomain.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @subdomain = Subdomain.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @subdomain = Subdomain.new(subdomain_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subdomain.save
        format.html { redirect_to @subdomain, notice: 'Subdomain was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subdomain }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @subdomain.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subdomain.update(subdomain_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @subdomain, notice: 'Subdomain was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @subdomain }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @subdomain.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @subdomain.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to subdomains_url, notice: 'Subdomain was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_subdomain_show
    redirect_to subdomain_url(@subdomain) if @request_subdomain.eql? @subdomain.address
  end

  # Redirect to subdomain... if the current one isn't equal to @subdomain.address column
  def redirect_to_subdomain
    redirect_to subdomain_url(@subdomain, subdomain: @subdomain.address) unless @request_subdomain.eql? @subdomain.address
  end

  def set_subdomain
    @subdomain = Subdomain.find(params[:id])
  end

  def subdomain_params
    @subdomain.assign_attributes(tag_speciality: params[:subdomain][:tag_speciality].split(','))
    params.require(:subdomain).permit(
      :domain_id,
      :address,
      :title,
      :description,
      :is_published,
      :button_text_client,
      :button_text_service,
      :cover,
      :primary_colour,
      :secundary_colour,
      :contrast_colour,
      :logo,
      :find_clients,
      :find_professional,
      :start_relation,
      :publications_wall,
      :tag_speciality,
      :cards_wall
    )
  end
end
```

On the view i created a condition:

```html
     <% if (!@subdomain.id.blank?) %>
         <li>
            <%= link_to cards_from_subdomain_path(subdomain_id: @subdomain.id) do %>
               <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>
               <span class="hidden-medium"> 
                 &nbsp <%= @subdomain.cards_wall %>
                </span>
            <% end %>
         </li>
         <li>
            <%= link_to publications_from_subdomain_path(subdomain_id: @subdomain.id) do %>
                 <i class="icon-grid fa-lg"></i> 
                 <span class="hidden-medium"> 
                   &nbsp <%= @subdomain.publications_wall %>
                 </span>
            <% end %>
         </li>
         <% else %>
         <li>Some thing</li>
     <% end %>
```

Here is the model:

```html
class Subdomain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :domain
  has_many :cards

  mount_uploader :cover, AssetsUploader
  mount_uploader :logo, AssetsUploader
end
```

When the @subdomain exist is ok, everything works fine, but when it doesn't exist, i get this error message:

```
NoMethodError in Subdomains#index
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
<% if (!@subdomain.id.blank?) %>
```

What could i do to fix that? thanks

Comment: `NoMethodError in Subdomains#index` Index?  What view is this?  Index only has `@subdomains` (plural).  Are you trying to loop through all the subdomains?

Comment: I is in the layouts/partials/_topnavbar.html.erb, for example if i go to other adress i get: NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new

Comment: Can you show your model and schema?

Comment: Yes @Afolabi Just added the model and schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution would be to use `#try` (not recommended though)

```
<% if !@subdomain.try(:id).try(:blank?) %>
```

By the way, you can use `#present?` instead of negating a `#blank?` to make code more readable.

However, if I assume correctly and the `@subdomain` is an ActiveRecord model, you don't need to check if it's id is present. A following code should be sufficient in your case:

```
<% if @subdomain %>
  (...)
<% else %>
  (...)
<% end %>
```

If the `@subdomain` is not found, it will be a `nil` anyway - and then the `if @subdomain` condition will be evaluated as false - since `nil` is a falsy value.

And if you get this error because you happen to be rendering a collection like this:

```
= render 'subdomain', collection: @subdomains
```

...then you can just put that inside a condition...

```
<% if @subdomains.present? %>
  = render 'subdomain', collection: @subdomains
<% else %>
  <% # @subdomains are an empty collection %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your `create action`, `id` will definitely be created in your table. I don't still understand what you are trying to get to, for negating on `#id.blank?`.

Change the first line from your view. i.e.

`<% if (!@subdomain.id.blank?) %>`

to,

`<% if @subdomains %>`, which will definitely return all attributes on your Subdomain Table since its has being taken care of in your index action.

Another thing I do is wrap my `if...else` statement inside a loop, such the your view becomes:

```
  <% @subdomains.each do |subd| %>  
         <% if subd.id.present? %> #you can use another attribute here instead of id. e.g. <% if subd.is_published == true %> since `is_published` is a boolean.
             <li>
                (#your codes here referenced with the format called `subd.whatever_attribute`)
             </li>
             <li>
                (#your codes here referenced with the format called `subd.whatever_attribute`)
             </li>
         <% else %>
             <li>Some thing</li>
         <% end %>
   <% end %>
```